Azure AI Search returns a document even if it does not contain the search term
I need to return the exact match first (higher score for sorting) and then any occurrence with a lower score for sorting.
Used query:
{
    "search": "\"axsdc\"^100 or /.*axsdc.*/",
    "queryType": "full"
}

It returns one specific document even if it does not contain the search term.
{
    "@odata.context": "...",
    "value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 18.317402,
        "ApplicationId": "45646",
        "Brand": "SUNNY",
        "CategoryId": 5684646,
        "Description": null,
        "DisplayName": "SUNNY LKE-Serie LKE 60 FU Robota V2607-OR-T-EW06 2021",
        "Engine": "Robota V2607-OR-T-EW06",
        "Model": "LKE-Serie",
        "Name": "LKE 60 FU",
        "Type": "LKE 60 FU\t2021\tRobota V2607-OR-T-EW06",
        "TypeNormalized": "LKE60FU2021RobotaV2607ORTEW06",
        "Year": "2021",
        "Timestamp": "2024-05-20T13:48:20.355Z"
    }
    ]
}

Searchable fields are Brand, Description, DisplayName, Engine, Model, Name, Type, TypeNormalized and Year.
I am expecting that the document will not be returned if it does not contain the search term.
Can someone please help me?

share your the Indexes, Indexers in the above question

also share what sample data you send

I have solved it. I just replaced 'or' with 'OR' because it is case-sensitive.

We can adjust your query to include both exact matches and partial matches with appropriate scoring, and then use $orderby to ensure exact matches are ranked higher.

The filter ensures that only documents containing the term 'axsdc' in the specified fields are returned.
The orderby parameter sorts the results first by the search score in descending order, ensuring that exact matches appear first, followed by any partial matches.

{
    "search": "axsdc^100 or axsdc*^10",
    "queryType": "full",
    "orderby": "search.score() desc"
}

{
    "search": "axsdc^100 or axsdc*^10",
    "queryType": "full",
    "orderby": "DisplayName asc"
}


